# Code to get lines which have values less or equal than given values in both columns

Tags: r, awk, sed

I have data which has three columns. In the first column I have `name`, while the second and third columns have one or more semicolon (;) separated values.

Now I want to print the rows where pairs of the semicolon separated column values have `distance <= 10` and `MAF >= 0.5`.

I would be happy if some one provide me R code, if not in R then AWK/SED.

Example

```
ID          Distance  MAF
cg12044689  8;40      0.000200;0.59
cg12143629  0;1;3     0.000200;0.520;0.0413
cg12247699  42        0.599
cg12375698  1;10      0.00231;0.51
```

Output should be:

```
ID          Distance  MAF
cg12143629  0;1;3     0.000200;0.520;0.0413
cg12375698  1;10      0.00231;0.51
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` script that accomplishes the task by splitting and comparing the pairwise values:

*parse.awk*

```
{
  # For each row, split the distance and maf columns into the dist and maf arrays
  n = split($2, dist, ";"); split($3, maf, ";")
  do {
    if (dist[n] <= 10 && maf[n] >= 0.5)
      print
  } while(n-- >= 1)
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f ./parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
cg12143629  0;1;3     0.000200;0.520;0.0413
cg12375698  1;10      0.00231;0.51
```